# Prevent # anchor in an iframe from scrolling the browser window

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

When a page loads an iframe with a url ending in a #, the parent page scrolls so that the iframe's body is at the top of the browser window.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dTQEE/1/

If the URL ends in `#`, e.g. `http://foo.com#`, the browser assumes you want to go to the top of the page.

How do you prevent the parent window from scrolling when an iframe with a hash fragment is loaded?

Problem happens in Chrome, not sure if it's an issue in other browsers.

Right now the best solution I have is to use `el.addEventListener('scroll', ...)` to reset the `scrollTop` to 0 if it's not already 0. This works, but the scroll down and the scroll up are both very noticeable.

Comment: How are you getting the URL for the frame? Is it not possible to check/edit before loading it?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the # might have some significance to the website receiving it. JS on the page inside the iframe might be using it, so I can't just strip it off completely.

Comment: was this ever resolved for you?

Comment: @spyroboy Nope. Resorted to using `addEventListener`. It's annoying, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is possible, but you should try to tap into window.onhashchange event and prevent default. If not, you'll have to strip the hash if it's not followed by anything.

Comment: Thanks - I tried that before. The onhashchange only gets fired when the hash of a page changes, so it doesn't get fired on load.

Comment: In chrome at least, (not sure about other browsers), the onhashchange event has cancelable set to false, so you can't use preventDefault on the event.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I came across it in my search for the same problem. I just came up with a solution that works wonderfully for me in Chrome.

```
<a href="dummylink.html" onclick="someFunction(); return false;">
```

The `href` link is used for the status bar, but because of the `return false;` at the end, it doesn't actually go anywhere. Then, you just do your redirection (in my case it was a `document.formName.submit();`) inside your `someFunction();`. Come to think of it though, you could do everything inline, but that doesn't really seem good form unless you only have one thing to do.

**Note:** If your `someFunction();` has `return false;` at the end, that will not be sufficient to prevent the jumping.